# FragmentTabHost prevent load loaded tab.

Tags: android, performance

I'm trying to use FragmentTabHost create tab like instagram. may i know how can i prevent the page load again once the tab has been pressed in 2nd time. i want it load again when receive some condition like updated from other tab. Any idea or other way?

Example code is better, please help thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can read this tutorial: http://android.codeandmagic.org/2011/07/android-tabs-with-fragments/

And focus on onTabChanged() method you can resolve your problems.

Comment: is that work for FragmentTabhost? because the given link are using TabHost instead of FragmentTabHost